# Unable to display the server side error message to the user when using retrofit on the application side

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

My requirement is to display various error messages that are sent by the server to the end user.

The API's written at the server are restful services.

**For example:**

At the server side, 400 code is generated when a user enters the wrong user name/password.

I try to execute API's written at the server side through Retrofit at application end.

400 bad request is generated by the server when the user gives wrong inputs for Username/Password.

At this point, only `onError()` method is getting executed and instead of executing `onNext()` method.

If `onNext()` gets executed I will be able to show server-side error messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not how it works when you integrate Retrofit with rxjava.

When you get a response code that is not 2XX Retrofit will error the steam causing the `onError` method to be called. From there, you'd need to get the response error body from the exception. This is a really simple way of doing it:

```
public void onError(Throwable e){
    if ( e instanceOf HttpException) {
       HttpException error = (HttpException)e;
       String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().string();
       // now you can parse the error or simply show it
    }
}
```

Please be aware that not all exceptions will be `HttpException` and might require different handling.

Comment: Are there any other libraries other than retrofit(Like Volley, OkHttp, etc.,) to execute the above scenario(error 400) and display the result from the server?

Comment: I suppose any library can do that, even Retrofit. It's just the way you chose to integrate Retrofit with rxjava that makes you have to handle it in `onError`.